# Problem in IOP template in two columns and references

Tags: bibliographies

I want to use the IOP template from this link:

[IOP Template](http://authors.iop.org/atom/help.nsf/0/B042B0AF79C815B88025702000409514?OpenDocument)

In this template, I have two problems:

1) The references, I want to cite my references in the context of my paper. I've tried to cite any reference but I could not.

For example:

Welcom for you all `\cite{simmons1971conduction}`.

---

The bibliography of the above citation is:

```
@article{simmons1971conduction,
    title={Conduction in thin dielectric films},
    author={Simmons, JG},
    journal={Journal of Physics D: Applied Physics},
    volume={4},
    number={5},
    pages={613},
    year={1971},
    publisher={IOP Publishing}
}
```

Here is the latex code

```
\documentclass[10pt]{iopart}
\newcommand{\gguide}{{\it Preparing graphics for IOP Publishing journals}}

%Uncomment next line if AMS fonts required

%\usepackage{iopams}  

\begin{document}

\title[Author guidelines for IOP Publishing journals in  \LaTeXe]{How to `prepare and submit an article for` 

publication in an IOP Publishing journal using \LaTeXe}

\author{Content \& Services Team}

\address{IOP Publishing, Temple Circus, Temple Way, Bristol BS1 6HG, UK}

\ead{submissions@iop.org}

\vspace{10pt}

\begin{indented}

\item[]February 2014

\end{indented}

\begin{abstract}

This document describes the  abstract.

\end{abstract}

% Uncomment for PACS numbers
%\pacs{00.00, 20.00, 42.10}
%

% Uncomment for keywords
%\vspace{2pc}
%\noindent{\it Keywords}: XXXXXX, YYYYYYYY, ZZZZZZZZZ
%

% Uncomment for Submitted to journal title message
%\submitto{\JPA}
%
% Uncomment if a separate title page is required

%\maketitle
% 
% For two-column output uncomment the next line and choose [10pt] rather than [12pt] in the \documentclass declaration
\ioptwocol

%


\section{Introduction: file preparation and submission}

Welcom for you all \cite{simmons1971conduction}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your MWE is missing a `\bibliography` statement.

Comment: I used \bibliography but did not work with me. Can you please tell me how to do it?

Comment: \bibliographystyle{apsrev}
\bibliography{Ref}

but not work

Comment: You're probably missing three statements: A `\bibliographystyle` directive (recommended argument: `iopart-num`); the instruction `\section*{References}`, and a `\bibliography{...}` statement. After providing the missing pieces, be sure to rerun LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more to propagate all changes.

Comment: Unfortunately not work with me. My knowledge is limited in Latex

Answer (score 1):

Adding the instructions

```
\section*{References}
\bibliographystyle{iopart-num}
\bibliography{testtesttest}
```

toward the end of the document, followed by recompiling via LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more, should generate the bibliography as well as the citation call-outs.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}  % just to make this example self-contained
\begin{filecontents}{testtesttest.bib}
@article{simmons1971conduction,
    title={Conduction in thin dielectric films},
    author={Simmons, J G},
    journal={Journal of Physics D: Applied Physics},
    volume={4},
    number={5},
    pages={613},
    year={1971},
    publisher={IOP Publishing}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[10pt]{iopart}

\begin{document}

\title[Author guidelines]{How to prepare and submit an article for 
publication in an IOP Publishing journal using \LaTeXe}

\author{Content \& Services Team}

\address{IOP Publishing, Temple Circus, Temple Way, Bristol BS1 6HG, UK}

\ead{submissions@iop.org}

\vspace{10pt}

\begin{indented}

\item[]February 2014

\end{indented}

\begin{abstract}

This section contains the abstract.

\end{abstract}

\ioptwocol

\section{Introduction: File preparation and submission}

Welcome for you all \cite{simmons1971conduction}.

%% The following three instructions are new:


\section*{References}
\bibliographystyle{iopart-num}
\bibliography{testtesttest}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It showed me this error as you can see on this link:



http://i.stack.imgur.com/TVOFk.png

Comment: Also, how can I start the first column from the first page please?

Comment: @HishamAlghamdi - Well, the error message says that LaTeX has crashed because it can't write the `.aux` file. This probably happens because LaTeX doesn't have write access to the directory where the `.tex` file to be compiled is located.